# Difference between the 2 regression model

Tags: statistics, regression

How are they different? and why would would the second regression be more appropriate?

$ Y = A_1(x_1)^2 + e $
$ {\sqrt Y} = A_1x_1 + e $

My thoughts: Square root of a function makes the function more linear, so the second regression would be preferred due to this reason.

Comment: Because the second regression is linear regression and the first it NOT linear regression ($\mathbb E[Y|x]$ is not a linear function of $X$).

Comment: @YiningWang. May I strongly disagree ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You're certainly welcome to disagree, but I think there's no general "definition" of linear regression / linear models. Your definition works perfectly fine for fixed designs but for random designs there's a big difference so one cannot always ignore transform of $X$. My consideration is mostly motivated from a frequentist estimation perspective, that for any model satisfying $\mathbb E[Y|x] = \beta_0^\top x$ and $\mathbb E[xx^T]\succ 0$, OLS is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

A model is said linear **when it is linear with respect to its parameters**; this does not have anything to do with the variables.

For example, 
$$y=a+ b x^\pi+c e^{\sqrt{x^3+9}}+d \sin(8x)$$ is a multilinear model.

Answer (score 0):

Which regression you would prefer depends on what you think is the distribution of $e$.  Imagine that the data is generated (i.e., the "true model" is) with $e$ as Gaussian in your second equation.  Then if you changed to the first form, then the $e$ term would not longer have the Gaussian distribution and OLS would not be appropriate.

+1, btw on @Claude Leibovici's excellent remark.